# SailsJS conf.bootstrap fails to insert initial data

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to load initial data into a sails app (sails v1.0.2) from the bootstrap conf, but it fails with the error:

```
error: UsageError: Invalid initial data for new record.
Details:
  Missing value for required attribute `agentType`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined
```

Model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    agentType: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    amount: {
      type: 'number',
      defaultsTo: 0
    },
    application: {
      model: 'application'
    }
  },
};
```

My bootstrap file:

```
const agents = [
  {
    agentType: 'Java App Agent',
    amount: 30
  }, {
    agentType: '.NET App Agent',
    amount: 18
  }, {
    agentType: '.NET Machine Agent',
    amount: 33
  }, {
    agentType: 'Standalone Machine Agent',
    amount: 46
  }];

    module.exports.bootstrap = function(done) {
      agents.forEach(agent => {
        Agent.findOrCreate({
            agentType: agent.agentType,
            amount: agent.amount
          })
          .exec((error, agent) => {
            if (error) sails.log.error(error);
            sails.log.info('Created fixture agent', agent)
          })
      });
      done()
    };
```

I am starting the sails app with "sails lift --drop" command.

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @texh from Gitter pointed out:

> https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create
>
> ```
>  module.exports.bootstrap = function(done) {
>   agents.forEach(agent => {
>     Agent.findOrCreate(agent, agent)
>       .exec((error, agent) => {
>         if (error) sails.log.error(error);
>         sails.log.info('Created fixture agent', agent)
>       })
>   });
>   done()
> };
> ```
>
> You have to pass the search criteria and the inital values to set if a
>   record isn't found